# @media Queries for Accessible Devices

Tags: email, accessibility, html-email

I am developing a series of emails with an eye to ADA compliance. Sometimes marketing doesn't remember things like ALL-CAPS don't work well or italics. I have been looking for a media query for screen readers to work the same way `@media` works for device width or type.

Examples:

`@media screen and (max-width: 599px)`

`@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)`

I have not been able to locate any information. It's hard to believe nothing like this exists.

Comment: It's a privacy and sometimes a HIPAA thing (in the US).  You can't tell if a screen reader is being used.  It could potentially reveal medical issues.  It's a noble, thought, though.  All caps can be read, as well as italics, but if you were concerned, you could have an `aria-label` in mixed caps that goes with the all caps text.

Comment: @slugolicious, I am already doing `aria-label`. I'm trying to figure out if I can do a css for all-caps and still have it read fine. All-CAPS cause some issues with screen readers. These points are all for another question. I do appreciate your comment.

Comment: I understand, and it's a great question and I appreciate you focusing on accessibility.  Yes, sometimes upcase can read kind of funky but most screen reader users are (unfortunately) used to that.  Worst case is they scan the word a character at a time if the reading of it doesn't make sense. But if you can fix it, that's even better.  You just won't be able to query whether a screen reader is running.  It'd have to be a solution that works all the time no matter the browser size.

Answer (score -2):

> @media Queries for **Accessible Devices**

[...]

> I have been looking for a media query for **screen readers**

## There is no media query for screenreaders, nor for accessible devices

Screen readers are only a small part of accessibility devices

For instance a screen magnifier is an accessibility "device" used by more people than screenreader users.

Dyslexic people also may not like uppercase text, and do not use specific devices